# Java how to check which condition is true

Tags: java

Is there anyway to make the program say which condition is correct?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  Boolean a = true;
  Boolean b = false;
  Boolean c = null;

  if (a == true || b == false || c == true) {
    System.out.println("Test");
  }
}
```

Since `a` is the only one that is correct, would there be a way to make it print `"a is the only condition that is correct"`

Comment: `a` and `b` cases are both "correct" in this example.

Comment: Use three individual if statements? And you can simply  do `if (a)`

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ yea sry about that mistype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (a) {
    System.out.println("a is the condition that is correct");
}
//Edit by comment. Thanks
if (!b) {
    System.out.println("b is the condition that is correct");
}

if (c) {
    System.out.println("c is the condition that is correct");
}
```

Comment: Will put as answer as soon as it allows.

Comment: And of course `!b` is the shorter version of `b == false`.

Comment: You might want to use else-if if only one can be true at a time.